# How Can I make any View Rounded In Ball Shape Even In Big Screens Like iPad when this view equal height , width to it's superView

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift5, xcode12

### The Question

---

how can I keep Buttons, Images, Buttons...Views rounded in big screens when using constraints of ( buttons, images....views ) equal width and height to superview using swift

---

### The Code I've Tried

I tried this block of code and It works fine in small screens like SE..until 8 :

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
roundedObject.layer.cornerRadius = roundedObject.frame.width / 2
roundedObject.clipsToBounds = true
}
```

[the shape of the different sizes screens](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EMH91.png)

my object constraints:
[screen1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pr8q7.png) [screen2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SebaS.png)  [screen3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NdRRf.png)

Comment: where you put the code that you have tried?

Comment: What does "this view equal height" mean?

Comment: @aiwiguna in override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
         roundedBackButton.layer.cornerRadius = roundedBackButton.frame.width / 2
        roundedBackButton.clipsToBounds = true
    }

Comment: @ElTomato I mean when I put the constraints in storyboard I set the constraints 30 in width and 30 in height then I drag from the view itself to it's super view and set equal height and I did also the same with width

Comment: can you try to print(roundedObject.frame) in viewDidLayoutSubviews()?

Comment: in iPhone 8 (16.0, 30.0, 40.0, 40.0)
                   (16.0, 30.0, 40.0, 40.0)
                   (16.0, 30.0, 40.0, 40.0)
in iPad.  the same but    (16.0, 30.0, 86.5, 65.0)

Comment: 86.5, 65.0 -> this the issue, it not a square. it thinks there is some issue with your constraint

Comment: @aiwiguna that what I realized from your code too. can you tell me how can I set the width and height equal to the width and height to it's superview to prevent this issue for all screen sizes

Comment: please share your current constraint, because it may be your superview is not a square too

Comment: @aiwiguna pls see my constraints images in my edited question

Comment: remove one of your proporsional height or width constraint and use aspect ratio constraint 1:1 on roundedObject, or just use a constant value for height and width

Comment: you will not get a square by using proportional width and proportional height constraint together like that, because different device will have different height and width

Comment: @aiwiguna now I got it thank you I didn't realized that until you told me
 thank you the issue has been solved now and the object now is rounded in different screen sizes  <3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the issue is your constraint

you will not get a square by using proportional width and proportional height constraint together like that, because different device will have different height and width

my suggestion is to use **only one** proportional width or proportional height (which one you want) and use **aspect ratio constraint 1:1** on the roundedObject

Comment: thank you it works now when I followed your instructions ..<3

Answer (score 0):

Probably you're doing that in `viewDidLoad` method where the frames didn't get the final value yet (initially they get the values from the storyboard from where they were instantiated. So if in the storyboard preview the size is f.e. 300x300, in the viewDidLoad it also will be 300x300).
So either do that in the `viewDidLayoutSubviews` or create a subclass and do that in the layoutSubviews.

```
class RoundedButton: UIButton {
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        layer.corderRadius = bounds.width / 2
        layer.masksToBounds = true
    }

}
```

Comment: this what I've already tried and it did't work sorry for not saying that I've tried this in viewDidLayoutSubviews you can look at my attached image in the question to know what I mean

Comment: Did you try the LayoutSubviews approach?

Comment: yes and I've tried your code of LayoutSubViews and set the class to my button and gave me the issue in the attached image